# Microphone not working in zoom, works in everything else

Tags: ubuntu, microphone, zoom

Somehow, and very suddenly, my microphone is not working for zoom (I have Ubuntu 20.04). I have updated to the latest version of Zoom (16.04+), have reverted back to the old version (12.04), and the new version again and nothing works. Strangely enough, the microphone works for Skype, and for every other app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try to install `pavucontrol` and in the Recording tab, check the input source for Zoom.

Comment: Have you checked that Zoom is using the right microphone device? There are sometimes >1 devices (even if you don't actually have >1) and switching between them fixes the issue.

Comment: @terdon I have: it shows two options, using the default system device, and using the actual microphone (I forgot the name right now and I am away from my laptop). I tried both with no success.

Comment: @pLumo Thanks a lot. I'll try that.